# How to enforce constraints on document attribute values in ArangoDB?

Tags: database-design, nosql, constraints, arangodb, aql

I would like documents in a collection to have values that are restricted to a small set of values. For example, a document's `my_type` attribute can be set to a value of only one of `a, b, c, or d`.

How can this be done in ArangoDB?

I do **not** wish to do it in front-end application logic, and I hope my only choice is **not** a Foxx microservice. Maybe I'm trying to think in SQL too much, but I hope to have a relational-type constraint at the database level. Is this possible in ArangoDB? How would it be done?

Comment: There is the idea of server-side schema validation, but it's not clear how it should work exactly and it could be tricky to implement for clusters. I added a link to your post here to an internal ticket. BTW. something similar was asked before, also with Foxx as the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47828441/model-schema-for-vertices-and-edges

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That cannot be done without Foxx applying joi or some other schema validation, because ArangoDB is schemaless. Only enforcement which you can apply on collection without Foxx is unique index on some attribute.